# Breaking ties in django template dictsort

Tags: django, django-templates

I've got models like this:

```
class Subject(models.Model):
   sid = models.CharField(max_length=5)

class TimePoint(models.Model):
   tpid = models.CharField(max_length=3)
   subject = models.ForeignKey(Subject)
```

I'm using the default `ListView` with `queryset=TimePoint.objects.all()`. In my template, I'm iterating over the list with `{% for tp in timepoint_list|dictsort:"subject.sid" %}`. The order of multiple timepoints referencing the same subject is coming out of `dictsort` unpredictably.

How can I implement the "tie breaker" for timepoints that reference the same subject

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try sorting by tpid first:

```
{% for tp in timepoint_list|dictsort:"tpid"|dictsort:"subject.sid" %}
```